# Importing excel file java

Tags: java, mysql, excel

When importing my excel file into mysql database there is a null for every empty cell in the database.

This is what i have so far:

```
if(jobRecord.equals(null)){
    log.info("row is blank");
}
else{
    log.info("row is not blank, adding now");
    jr.add(jobRecord);

    jobRecord = new JobRecord();
}
```

Comment: So what is your question, actually?

Comment: Please check your code first. If jobRecord is null you will get a NullPointerException at if(jobRecord.equals(null))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use a exccelent api named [Java Excel API](http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html). It is easy to use and fast.

```
import java.io.File; 
import java.util.Date; 
import jxl.*; 
import jxl.write.*; 

Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("myfile.xls"));
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
Cell a1 = sheet.getCell(0,0); 
Cell b2 = sheet.getCell(1,1); 
Cell c2 = sheet.getCell(2,1); 

String stringa1 = a1.getContents(); 
String stringb2 = b2.getContents(); 
String stringc2 = c2.getContents(); 

//save data in database.
```